# Prove that $ [\forall x \in R,f(X)>0] \implies (a>0 \ and \ b^2-4ac<0) $

Tags: logic

$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$   The first part of the question was to prove that $f(k)=\frac{64+(b^2-4ac)^2}{64a} $ when $k=-\frac{b}{2a} +\frac1a+\frac{b^2-4ac}{8a}$
The next part was,Hence **without using graphs or your prior knowledge on quadratic functions and equations,** prove that

$[\forall x \in R,f(X)>0] \implies (a>0 \ and \ b^2-4ac<0)$

This is how I tried it, 
Case1 - Suppose a=-1,b=0 and c=0

Then,  $ f(x)=-x^2 \implies  f(x)<0, \ \ \forall x \in R \\ \therefore a<0 \implies \exists x \in R, f(x)<0 \to eqn1$

Case2 - Suppose a=1,b=-3 and c=2

Then$ f(x)=x^2-3x+2 = (x-1)(x-2)\\ for\ 1<x<2, \ f(x)<0, \ \ \exists x \in R \\ \therefore b^2-4ac>0 \implies \exists x \in R, \ f(x)<0 \to eqn2 $

From  eqn1 and eqn2 $\\a<0 \ or\ b^2-4ac>0 \implies \exists x \in R, \ f(x)<0 \\\therefore \forall x \in R, \ f(x)>0\implies a>0\ and\ b^2-4ac<0 \ \to ( \because contrapositive) $

**Is it correct?** But I'm stuck on the next one.

The next part was,

Hence **without using graphs or your prior knowledge on quadratic functions and equations,** prove that$
 [\forall x \in R,f(X)>0]$ will hold only when both $a>0$ and $b^2-4ac<0$ holds.

I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Please don't include text inside $\$'$s, unless you explicitly enclose it in `\text{.}`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this and am still learning about posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A=ax^2+bx+c$$
$$\frac{A}{a}=x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}\implies \frac{A}{a}=(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$
or
$$A=a\big((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}\big)*$$
Let
$$\Delta=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$
If $\Delta\gt 0,$ then A will have two roots contradicting our assumption. Therefore $\Delta\lt 0$.

So $$b^2-4ac\lt 0$$
It follows that $$(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$
is always positive. Now positivity of $A$ with equation $*$ implies that $a$ must be positive.

Comment: But the questions says not to use previous knowledge on quadratic equations and graphs. So is this method correct?

Comment: what previous knowledge we've used?

Comment: You have stated "If $\Delta\gt 0$ then A will have two roots contradicting our assumption" What assumption have we made?

Comment: $f(x)\gt 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$